# Managing StreamingContext in across multiple applications on same JVM

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

According to [spark streaming documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html) :

> Only one `StreamingContext` can be active in a JVM at the same time.

I have some scenario wherein multiple application can try starting streaming context in same JVM.

As an attempt to handle this scenatio gracefully, I am using following code:

```
private static StreamingContext getStreamingContext(SparkSession spark) {
    if (StreamingContext.getActive().isEmpty()) {
        return new StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext(), getBatchDuration(spark));
    } else {
        return StreamingContext.getActive().get();
    }
}
```

Is above approach is correct or I should wait for termination of existing streaming context and create new something like this:

```
private static StreamingContext getStreamingContext(SparkSession spark) {
    if (StreamingContext.getActive().isDefined()){
        StreamingContext.getActive().get().awaitTermination();
    }
    return new StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext(), getBatchDuration(spark));
}
```

I am creating `JavaStreamingContext` like this:

```
JavaStreamingContext jsc = new JavaStreamingContext(getStreamingContext(spark));
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using `JavaStreamingContext`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I am using `JavaStreaminContext`. Updated the code. Also I can't see `JavaStreaminContext#getActive()` method. Hence using `StreamingContext#getActive()`.